# Keep keyboard open on focus change between inputs

Tags: javascript, cordova, keyboard

I am building a simple app with ionic. On one of the pages I have several input fields. When I move from one input field to the other, the keyboard closes and opens again. I want to keep the keyboard open even if the blur event is fired on the first input field. I tried to add listeners and prevent the default behavior of 'blur' event but it still does fire.

```
window.addEventListener('native.hidekeyboard', keyboardHideHandler, true);
document.body.addEventListener('focusout', keyboardHideHandler, true);
function keyboardHideHandler(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Is there a way to keep the keyboard open through event handling in javascript?

Comment: If input is blur, where will it type ?

Comment: The blur event is fired during focus change. So the user has already typed on the first input field and he's switching focus to second input field. At that time blur event is fired for the first input field and the keyboard hides. Almost immediately the focus event is fired for the second input where user has now clicked and keyboard comes up again. I am trying to avoid this hide and show behavior while switching between inputs. I want the keyboard to stay open at all times.